# SSL Client Certificate validation with Nginx ngx_stream_ssl_module

Tags: nginx

As per https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html, ngx_stream_ssl_module does not support ssl_client_certificate/ssl_verify_client.

Is there another way to have client certificates authenticated for TCP stream configuration?

Comment: You need the stream ssl module. compile --with-stream_ssl_module. See https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html#ssl_client_certificate